# Why is the function $(-2)^{x}$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, exponential-function

[image]

If we work over complex mumbers we have

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(-2)^{\frac πx}=(-2)^0=1$$

But, if we work over $\Bbb R$ then

the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}(-2)^{\frac πx}$ should be undefined.  Because, as far as I know $a^x$ is not well defined if $a<0$ and $x\not\in \Bbb Z$. Thus I couldn't understand. Why is the function $(-2)^{x}$ continuous? What does Wolfram mean?

Comment: Over $\Bbb{R}$, you’re right, the function is not well defined so it wouldn’t make sense to speak about its continuity. Over $\Bbb{C}$, once you make a specific choice of branch for $\log$, you can interpret this suitably.

Comment: I think WolframAlpha is treating $(-2)^x$ as a complex valued function. For $a<0$, it is standard to define the expression $a^t$ as $\exp(t\log(a))$, where $\log$ denotes the principal branch of the complex logarithm. For our case of $a=-2$ and $t=\pi/x$, we can easily see that the limit will be $0$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: $a^x$ is also defined if $x$ is a rational number with odd denominator.  But that would be wildly discontinuous since the sign fluctuates based on whether the numerator is even or odd, and both cases are dense.

Comment: I agree with @AlannRosas ... unless you specify something else, Wolfram Alpha assumes complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(-2)^x = e^{x \ln(-2)} = e^{x (\ln(2) + i \pi)}$, which is continuous as a function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $\ln$ is principal branch of the logarithm. That is : the one with imaginary part in $(-\pi,\pi ]$